# ASP.NET Core 2.2 InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm working on asp.net core web api application with entity framework core. Recently I updated application to support .net core 2.2 framework. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 as a code editor.

After upgrading the project few weird exceptions are occurring at runtime, those are as follows.

1. Earlier I was able to add code migrations script easily but now 
   it is throwing an exception 'Unable to create an object of type '...DbContext'.
2. After running project, 1st request getting served without an exception but consecutive request are failing with an error `AggregateException`: One or more errors occurred as per below screen-shot. (The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.)

I observed error is throwing by `CheckPasswordAsync` method of `UserManager` class which belongs to Asp.net Identity provider.

[image]

Comment: Show your code please. Startup.cs and controller

Comment: How did you migrate asp.net identity to asp.net core identity? Follow [Migrate Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @TonyNgo Hi Tony, please check my startup.cs at https://www.codepile.net/pile/8l10R6gQ URL. Thank you!

Comment: @TaoZhouI initially I was using visual studio 2017. So I installed .net 2.2 core framework first and then changed framework from project properties. Later on I installed Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @TonyNgo. Exception is occurring while retrieving authentication token. Application is returning authentication token for first request but when I'm triggering same request again with same username and password its not working. I'm using postman to trigger request for testing

Comment: Issue got resolved!  using (DbConnection dbConn = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()) this line was creating problem. it was disposing DbContext object. Replacing line with var dbConn = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection(); resolved this issue